# Restructuring messy data with unequal columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a very messy data set that looks like this:

```
Person1
Answer1  10  3
Answer2  4   12  5
Person2
Answer2  12  3   4   19  23
Answer3  3   14  22
```

I would like to turn it into this:

```
              Person1  Person2
Answer1       10
Answer2       4
Answer2       12
Answer2       5
Answer2                  12
Answer2                  3
Answer2                  4
Answer2                  19
Answer2                  23
Answer3                  3
Answer3                  14
Answer3                  22
```

I'm completely lost on this. I tried the following for loop to try to extract the data from the original column into a clean data set:

```
  for(i in 1:nrow(dat)){
   for(j in 2:ncol(dat)){
    if(!is.na(dat[i,j])){
      dat.clean[i+1,2]<-dat[i,j]
      dat.clean[i,1]<-dat[i,1]
    }else{}
  }
}
```

But I'm getting complete garbage out. Any help would be appreciated!

Output:

```
  X1 X2
1    5 NA
2    2  5
3    3  3
4    1  5
5    3  6
6    4 23
7   NA 22
```

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the example

Comment: Is this a text file?

Comment: It's a csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit complicated but with the example dataset, saved as a CSV file, it works.

```
txt <- readLines("messydata.csv")
txt <- txt[sapply(txt, nchar) != 0]

answer <- NULL
Data <- list()

for(x in txt){
  value <- NULL
  if(grepl("person", x, ignore.case = TRUE)) {
    curr <- unlist(strsplit(x, ","))
    curr <- curr[sapply(curr, nchar) != 0]
  }
  if(grepl("answer", x, ignore.case = TRUE)){
    y <- unlist(strsplit(x, ","))
    y <- y[sapply(y, nchar) != 0]
    answer <- c(answer, rep(y[1], length(y) - 1))
    value <- scan(text = y[-1])
    Data[[curr]] <- c(Data[[curr]], value)
  }
}

n <- length(answer)
s <- 0L
for(i in seq_along(Data)){
  d <- length(Data[[i]])
  Data[[i]] <- c(rep(NA, s), Data[[i]], rep(NA, n - s - d))
  s <- s + d
}

result <- data.frame(Answer = answer, do.call(cbind, Data))
result
#    Answer Person1 Person2
#1  Answer1      10      NA
#2  Answer1       3      NA
#3  Answer2       4      NA
#4  Answer2      12      NA
#5  Answer2       5      NA
#6  Answer2      NA      12
#7  Answer2      NA       3
#8  Answer2      NA       4
#9  Answer2      NA      19
#10 Answer2      NA      23
#11 Answer3      NA       3
#12 Answer3      NA      14
#13 Answer3      NA      22
```

Final clean up.

```
rm(txt, answer, Data)
```